# how to uninstall notepad from Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: ubuntu, wine

There is a program named `notepad` on my Ubuntu which I want to remove as I never use it. I have got update for notepad of 80 MB from `software updater`. And I don't want to download that 80 MB.

I entered `.wine` folder of my home directory & there deleted the program named `notepad`. Still when I run the command `notepad` on terminal, the notepad window opens. To find where this program is, I did:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ which notepad
/usr/bin/notepad
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ sudo apt-get purge notepad
[sudo] password for ravbholua: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package notepad
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$
```

So, what's the package name for this program? This program runs on wine (this I came to know after seeing the menu item named 'about notepad' for this program). How come this run on wine as the program name wine I deleted from the directory tree under `~/.wine` and there is no other program named notepad under this folder?

#### EDIT #1

W.R.T. to an answer, I'm posting the below:

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ dpkg-query --search notepad
wine1.7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/wine-notepad.png
wine1.7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/wine-notepad.png
wine1.7: /usr/share/applications/wine-notepad.desktop
wine1.7-i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/fakedlls/notepad.exe
wine1.7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/wine-notepad.png
wine1.7: /usr/share/man/man1/notepad.1.gz
wine1.7: /usr/bin/notepad
wine1.7-i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/notepad.exe.so
wine1.7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/wine-notepad.png
wine1.7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/wine-notepad.png
wine1.7: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/notepad-48.svg
kdelibs5-plugins: /usr/lib/kde4/notepadpart.so
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$
```

From this, what's the package name of notepad?

> EDIT#2

The answer wrote by @slm has worked with the following note.

Earlier I was getting an update for wine for 80.2 MB. Then after holding `wine1.7` using command `sudo apt-mark hold wine1.7`, I got update for ~50MB. So, I understood it's working. Now to hold everything on wine, I did the following.

```
ravbholua@ravbholua-Aspire-5315:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep wine
wine-gecko2.24:i386                                 install
wine-mono0.0.8                                      install
wine1.4                                             install
wine1.4-i386                                        install
wine1.7                                             hold
wine1.7-i386                                        install
winetricks                                          install
```

I see here that the package `wine1.7` which I had held from update is only marked as hold. So, I ran the below to hold all these.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold wine-gecko2.24:i386 wine-mono0.0.8 wine1.4 wine1.4-i386 wine1.7 wine1.7-i386 winetricks
```

And now I'm not getting the update at all.

Comment: each line start with `wine1.7` I assume you need to remove wine to remove this `notpead` binary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `readlink` to track down errant links to files, so that you can find out the true executable behind the link.

#### Example

*link*

```
$ ls -l /sbin/reboot
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 Dec 16 11:38 /sbin/reboot -> ../bin/systemctl
```

*real file*

```
$ readlink -f /sbin/reboot
/usr/bin/systemctl

$ ls -l /usr/bin/systemctl
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 337048 Dec  8 22:20 /usr/bin/systemctl
```

#### Determining what package a file belongs to

You need to use `apt` to find out what the actual package name, since `notepad` likely belongs to a package, and isn't necessarily its own package.

*using apt*

```
$ apt-file search notepad

-or-

$ apt-file search /usr/bin/notepad
```

*using dpkg*

You can also use `dpkg` to find out more as well:

```
$ dpkg-query --search notepad
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/icons/wine-notepad.png
kdelibs5-plugins: /usr/lib/kde4/notepadpart.so
app-install-data: /usr/share/app-install/desktop/wine1.4:wine-notepad.desktop
```

#### Excluding packages from update

If you need to block an application from being considered for updating by APT you can use one of the following commands.

```
$ sudo -i
$ echo “wine hold” | dpkg --set-selections

-or-

$ sudo apt-mark hold wine
```

You can confirm using these commands:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep wine
wine                                        hold
wine-gecko1.4:amd64                         install
wine-gecko1.4:i386                          install
wine1.4                                     install
wine1.4-amd64                               install
wine1.4-i386                                install
winetricks                                  install

-or-

$ apt-mark showhold
wine
```

But I think there's an issue with excluding just the package named "wine". I believe you also want to exclude `wine1.7` in your case, here it would be `wine1.4` for me.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold 'wine1.4'

$ apt-mark showhold
wine
wine1.4
```

If you continue to encounter additional warnings about "wine" packages you might want to "hold" everything related to wine.

Comment: I have shown the output of the dpkg--query in my edit. Please say what's the package name for notepad. It is not clear to me.

Comment: Also please say whether both `ls -l` & `readlink` would give the link? If so, then either can be used & not necessarily `readlink`. In my case `readlink` didn't show any link; so it means it has no link!! Am I right?

Comment: @Ravi - `wine1.7` is the package. This app is provided by `wine` itself.

Comment: @Ravi - correct on the link Q. I was showing that on the off chance that you were dealing w/ a link to a program which wasn't under control of any package that was install via APT.

Comment: Thanks slm. Also @Kiwy what I want is to get rid of the update message from the software updater to update notepad. So, if I delete the executable using `sudo rm`, will it solve my purpose? And also as per mart's answer (in comment section), will wine work properly even if the executable is removed?

Comment: @Ravi - if you remove notepad wine should work just fine otherwise. That's the executable for the text editor notepad that comes with windows.

Comment: slm & @mart I was getting an update from software updater to update notepad of 80.2MB. I deleted `/usr/bin/notepad` successfully using `rm`. But my purpose couldn't be solved. Now the updater says `Configure Wine` & its download size is the same 80.2 MB.

Comment: @Ravi - rather than try and remove it, why not just exclude wine from any further updates? You can use the command: `sudo apt-mark hold wine` to do this.

Comment: I ran the command `sudo apt-mark hold wine` & it had output `wine set on hold`. But still I get the update message for wine!! I read the man page for apt-mark; it says `hold` option will stop it from automatically getting installed/upgraded. So, it seems it will show those (marked hold) update also.

Comment: @Ravi - you want those completely gone? You don't want any mention of wine at all when doing updates?

Comment: that's right. Now how to do that?

Comment: @Ravi - how about this: `echo “wine hold” | dpkg --set-selections`?

Comment: slm, I'm still getting the update for wine for 80.2 MB. When I ran the above command, it took a moment and after that the prompt returned without any message.

Comment: @Ravi - see updates.

Comment: @Ravi - other methods listed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package

Answer (score 0):

the location in `/usr/bin/notepad` is probably a link to some other location. Try `ls -lh /usr/bin/notepad` to see where it's linked from.

Also use `dpkg-query` to search for the containing package, as in: `dpkg-query --search /usr/bin/notepad`. `man dpkg-query` for more information.

Comment: No I don't think so. Please see the output of the command you told `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.6K Dec  7 02:50 /usr/bin/notepad
`. Does it show that its not linked!!

Comment: then removing that file should do the job. However, is notepad not necessary for wine?
In the file list here is it included, I think this is because some windows programs depend on it: http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise-updates/i386/wine1.4/filelist

Comment: @Ravi - did you run `dpkg-query --search`?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I run successfully on Ubuntu 17.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove notepadqq
```